# Programming "Add Method" array seems to not be working

Tags: java

Hi, I'm very new to java and I'm currently trying to create a student name and mark menu but I'm having trouble with my add method, I think it's something to do with my Arrays but I can't figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Below is my `unitResult` method

```
public class UnitResults 
{
    private String unitTitle;
    private String [] fName;
    private String [] surname;
    //private String [] UnitResults;
    private int [] Marks;
    private int Mark;

    private int pointer ;

    private static String course = "HND Computing"; 

    public UnitResults(int Size,String title)
    {            
        this.fName = new String [Size];
        this.surname = new String [Size];
        this.Marks = new int [Size];
        pointer = 0;

        fName[pointer] = "Daniel";
        surname[pointer] = "Scullion";

        Marks[pointer] = 60;
        unitTitle  = title;

        pointer ++;
    }

    public Boolean add( String tempfName, String tempsName, int newGrade)
    { 
        if (pointer == fName.length)
        {
            System.out.println("The Students Database is full");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            fName [pointer] = tempfName;
            surname [pointer]  = tempsName;
            Marks[pointer] = newGrade;

            pointer ++;
            return true;
        }
    }// end Add
```

but when I try to add this using a menu system below

```
int option = 0;
option = menuSystem();

while (option != 6)
{
    System.out.println("");
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students First Name");
        String tempfName = keyb.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Students Last Name");
        String tempsName = keyb.nextLine();

        System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students Mark");
        int newGrade = keyb.nextInt();
        myUnit.add(tempfName, tempfName,newGrade);   

        break;
```

When I enter my option 1 the output that I get is :

```
Please Enter The Students First Name

Please Enter The Students Last Name
```

Any ideas what's wrong here been searching for a long time, probably something simple but I've no idea :/

Edit: below is my menu class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuResults {
    static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int menuSystem()
    {
        System.out.println("*********************************");
        System.out.println("                                 ");
        System.out.println("1.Add New Student");
        System.out.println("2.Display Students Details");
        System.out.println("3.Delete a Students");
        System.out.println("4.Update Student Details");
        System.out.println("5.Sort Students By Mark");
        System.out.println("6.Sort Students By Surname");
        System.out.println("7.Search For A Student");
        System.out.println("                                 ");
        System.out.println("**********************************");

        System.out.print("\n Enter choice:");
        int option = keyb.nextInt();
        return option;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnitResults myUnit = new UnitResults(3, "Java");

        int option = 0;
        option = menuSystem();

        while (option != 6)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            switch(option)
            {
            case 1:                   

                System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students First Name");
                String tempfName = keyb.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Please Enter The Students Last Name");
                String tempsName = keyb.nextLine();

                System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students Mark");
                int newGrade = keyb.nextInt();
                myUnit.add(tempfName, tempsName,newGrade);   

                break;
            case 2:
                myUnit.display();
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

            case 6:

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" Invalid Entry");
            }//end switch 
        }
    }
}
```

There is my whole menu class as asked for.

EDIT: when I forget the user input and hard input it using: `myUnit.add("John","tommy",12);`

I get `"Student Database is full"` about one hundred times..

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong? The output appears to match what it should do.

Comment: What is keyb? Is it a Scanner? How is it defined?

Comment: it doesnt let me input the first option aka Students First Name and skips right to the last name. im really new to this so i hope its some simple mistake

Comment: yea its the scanner diego. its this "static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Where is the scanner code? Also, you probably meant myUnit.add(tempfName, tempsName,newGrade); Your code has tempfName twice.

Comment: The code works how programmer wrote it.

Comment: This is a terrible introduction to Java!

Comment: Can you paste what you do with keyb since you instantiate it? menuSystem may be consuming input from the Scanner.

Comment: i just pasted in my whole menu class above, i still cant see why the output is going like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess, when you use your menu and type <kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> a carriage return (`\n`) for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is still present in your `Scanner` after `nextInt()` is called.

So next call to `readLine()` will use the `\n` (remaining <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) for the line and will not wait for user input.

Possible correction:

```
public static int menuSystem()
{
    final Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    // ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final UnitResults myUnit = new UnitResults(3, "Java");
    int option = menuSystem();
    while (option != 6) {
        final Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        // ...
        option = menuSystem();
    }
}
```

And removal of the static `kbd` declaration

Comment: sorry i dont quite understand what you mean? im very very new to java

Comment: Thanks the above code sorted out the first problem but has shown me another.. it goes into a infinite loop with now asking me to keep inputting the details until the database is full(When 3 user details are entered)  and does not go back to the menu system when the student is added

Comment: Did you forget `option = menuSystem();` at the end of the while? (You can just debug that and see whats wrong)

Comment: Yea thats what i was forgetting! thanks alot for your help! cheers

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to simply call `keyb.nextLine()` after calling `keyb.nextInt()` to handle the end of line token. Quite simply change this:

```
System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students Mark");
int newGrade = keyb.nextInt();
myUnit.add(tempfName, tempsName,newGrade);
```

to this:

```
System.out.println(" Please Enter The Students Mark");
int newGrade = keyb.nextInt();
keyb.nextLine();  // ****** add this *******
myUnit.add(tempfName, tempsName,newGrade);
```